# How can you invoke a triggered send from a link in an email in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

All guides only point to invoking a triggered send from cloud pages, which I understand. I need to know how or if it is possible to invoke a triggered send just when clicking a link or button from an email(that was sent out of marketing cloud). The reason I want this functionality is to ensure that a user receives the triggered send only once.

Comment: One could argue on the validity of such a use case. Is the real time aspect really necessary? The workaround suggested by @user6079228 will work, but screw up your click tracking, as the “destination” URLs will not be visible in your click reporting

Comment: Where have you seen emails fired from a click in an email without an intermediary page?

Comment: I have not seen that. My question asks how (if possible).

Answer (score 1):

If you really need a real time notification, once a link has been clicked in an email, you can utilise the [ENS](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_ens.htm&type=5) which is a part of the new-ish Transactional Email feature of SFMC. The reason why I assume this is suitable for you, is the fact of you mentioning Triggered Sends:

> The reason I want this functionality is to ensure that a user receives
> the triggered send only once.

You can register a webhook to receive notifications as soon as a link has been clicked. This will provide your callback url with following payload:

```json
{
        "eventCategoryType": "EngagementEvents.EmailClick",
        "timestampUTC": 1591407815000,
        "compositeId": "1722201.69238.15596.177361590",
        "definitionKey": "NA",
        "definitionId": "NA",
        "channel": "email",
        "mid": 1476456,
        "eid": 1476266,
        "composite": {
            "jobId": "1722201",
            "batchId": "15596",
            "listId": "69238",
            "subscriberId": "177361590"
        },
        "info": {
            "ipAddress": "52.5.174.125",
            "jobUrlId": "74165311",
            "contentLink": "https://portal.makanahealth.com/memberID\u003d?18937918018\u0026cm_ven\u003dExactTarget\u0026cm_cat\u003dMakana+Member+Notifications\u0026cm_pla\u003dAll+Subscribers\u0026cm_ite\u003dhttps%3a%2f%2fportal.makanahealth.com%2fmemberID%3d%3f18937918018\u0026cm_lm\u003ddfallon.10064.0401@gmail.exacttargettest.com\u0026cm_ainfo\u003d\u0026att1\u003d\u0026att2\u003d%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute2%%\u0026att3\u003d%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute3%%\u0026att4\u003d%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute4%%\u0026att5\u003d%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute5%%",
            "impressionRegion": "0",
            "userAgent": "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; AskTB5.5; MSOffice 12)",
            "location": {
                "country": "US",
                "region": "VA",
                "city": "ASHBURN",
                "postalCode": "20146-20149",
                "latitude": "39.0438",
                "longitude": "-77.4879"
            }
        }
    }
```

What I would do, is to build a code resource in Cloud Pages, which you will expose as the callback URL. It will use SSJS to parse JSON and validate which link has been clicked (you probably don't want ALL clicks to trigger an email), lookup the subscriber info based on subscriber ID, and trigger a new transactional email using [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/transactional-messaging-get-started.htm).

This is the only solution, within the current scope of SFMC, which will allow for a real time triggering of an email based on click.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible directly, however some workarounds are available.

If you don't want subscribers to end up on a cloudpage, you can trigger the send from the cloudpage and redirect the subscriber to an external page right after the trigger.

You can also create an automation that checks the _click data view. After a click, the send can be triggered. With this option there is a delay, and performance technical I am not a fan of it, although it depends on how much data comes into _click.

If you are linking to your own website, you can build a trigger there server side. But again, not an ideal solution in my opinion.